# iOS- Ways to launch application

Tags: ios, iphone, uiapplication, launching-application

I have an on-air application and I block some old version (must to update).

I noticed that an old version (version I blocked) don't have "must upgrade" appear.

To solve that issue, in thought all the ways to launch my application:

1. Tap the app icon
2. Schemas (Url)
3. Push notifications

Are there any other ways?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Block launch application from an old version, and send the user to app store. But the problem is the blocking.

Comment: What's wrong with `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `applicationDidBecomeActive:`?

Comment: I think the problem he is facing is the old version of his app doesn't take into account of "must upgrade" this version. Hence he cannot use that method - he is also wanting to block the app (old one) from launching)

Comment: The old version take into account "must upgrade". It's remote control...

Answer (score 1):

From what you're asking - those are the only ways to launch an app from an iOS device. Just update the app to a new version and users will get notified in the App Store of the new update. I don;t see how you can prevent the current app from running -- unless you are using a web service in the current app that you could disable in some way, prevent the app from functioning. But that sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a horrible idea - for example, you might change your API and don't want to or even cannot support the old version anymore. I'd rather have the old version of the app tell me I have to update because of an API change than to just crash on me ... Of course, that's a bit tricky to do if you did not think of that possibility before bringing out the first version of your app ;-).